# Why isSystemInDarkTheme() triggers recompostion

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am writing a very simple test app. Here is the code pieces,

```
class Holder{
    companion object{
        var a = 0
    }
}

@Composable
fun test(){
    if(!isSystemInDarkTheme()){
        Holder.a +=1
        Text("a is " + Holder.a)
    }
}
```

I simply set test() as content and there will be a text composable with value 2 displayed on the screen. When I remove isSystemInDarkTheme() usage , the value of text will be 1

Why isSystemInDarkTheme() causing recomposition?

Comment: Did you change the theme?

Comment: I'll broaden the question from Gabriele - did anything related to configuration changed? Might be even keyboard show/hide. Because `isSystemInDarkTheme()` on android relies on this class `LocalConfiguration.current`

Comment: I didn't change anything. I simply invoked isSystemInDarkTheme() in composable function as shown in my sample code

Comment: Changing the configuration does not matter. Replace `if(!isSystemInDarkTheme()){` with just `LocalConfiguration.current` line and it will be the same.`LocalConfiguration.current` causes the recomposition. While others Local* are not. Would like to understand why